# Can we assign a responsive web site to act like a Progressive Web Application?

Tags: node.js, progressive-web-apps

if we had a responsive web site with HTML, Css and Nodejs for it's back-end, can we make it to act like PWA application?
- I know the difference will the Service-worker file, but i wanna to find out is it the exact difference?

Comment: Yes, A PWA is just a website (responsive or not) with a few extra things added

Answer (score 1):

Here is the difference between [PWA(Progressive Web Application) and RWD(Responsive Web Design)](https://medium.com/altos-blog/responsive-design-vs-progressive-web-apps-the-push-for-pwas-f59ef1d6f6c8):

**PWA**

> Users access the website through any browser, and on a supported
>   browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and even Edge!) it asks the user if
>   they want to install the web app to their home screen. This lets users
>   download and the store the website on their devices (which then gets
>   updated with Service Workers in the background).

**RWD**

> Responsive web design (RWD) basically refers to the practice of
>   designing a website that can be accessed with any technology you might
>   use to build a site. RWD allows the website to be fully functional
>   (and look good) no matter what size screen the user has in front of
>   them. It has been around since 2001, when Audi launched the first
>   documented responsive site.

Therefore, PWAs and RWD are not two independent ways to create a website — in fact, PWAs will almost certainly utilize RWD.

**Here's some tips:**

The best solution is to choose the best solution for your particular site. If you’re looking to maximize those app-like features (like easy home screen app access, offline use, and high-quality, full screen functionality), you may want to choose a PWA.

If you’re looking to maximize site speed and accessibility for the most users, RWD might be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you can make a PWA without a service worker then i believe you can't since it (service worker) and the manifest.json file are both required to save an application to the homescreen.

from the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/):

> In order for a user to be able to install your Progressive Web App, it needs to meet the following criteria:
>
> - The web app is not already installed.
>
>   - and prefer_related_applications is not true.
> - Meets a user engagement heuristic (currently, the user has interacted with the domain for at least 30 seconds)
> - Includes a web app manifest that includes:
>
>   - short_name or name
>   - icons must include a 192px and a 512px sized icons
>   - start_url
>   - display must be one of: fullscreen, standalone, or minimal-ui
> - Served over HTTPS (required for service workers)
> - Has registered a service worker with a fetch event handler